# PHP - Convert function value into String

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to create table in database, where the fields from another table.

Create query save table:

```
create_table ="CREATE TABLE tbl_lstProjName (projNameNo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ". xFunction() ." PRIMARY KEY (projNameNo))";


mysqli_query($con,creat_table);
```

Function:

```
function xFunction{

     query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table");

     while($dataset = mysli_fetch_array()){
        $dataset['$dataset'] ."VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,";
     }

}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? Your question is unclear

Comment: Is there a way to put the value of a function into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No return value from that function. If you are trying to use the column definitions from another table then you should use http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_field.asp. Use that to get column names, datatype and size. Build the column definitions as a string and return the string. You also only need to get 1 row back to use the field definitions so add LIMIT 1 to the query.